# h264_cuvid codec not found

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm trying to encode, apply a filter and decode a video through GPU.

Im using H264_nvenc for encoding it, and trying to use h246_cuvid for the decoding, but FFMPEG can't find the decoder.

Here is where the problem is

```cpp
decodingCodec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("h264_cuvid");
if (!decodingCodec) {
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Codec not found DEC.\n");
    return;
}
```

**OS *win 10 x64***

EDIT:
I'm actually using Zeranoe FFmpeg with the following config

```
  --enable-gpl
  --enable-version3
  --enable-sdl2
  --enable-fontconfig
  --enable-gnutls
  --enable-iconv
  --enable-libass
  --enable-libbluray
  --enable-libfreetype
  --enable-libmp3lame
  --enable-libopencore-amrnb
  --enable-libopencore-amrwb
  --enable-libopenjpeg
  --enable-libopus
  --enable-libshine
  --enable-libsnappy
  --enable-libsoxr
  --enable-libtheora
  --enable-libtwolame
  --enable-libvpx
  --enable-libwavpack
  --enable-libwebp
  --enable-libx264
  --enable-libx265
  --enable-libxml2
  --enable-libzimg
  --enable-lzma
  --enable-zlib
  --enable-gmp
  --enable-libvidstab
  --enable-libvorbis
  --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
  --enable-libmysofa
  --enable-libspeex
  --enable-libxvid
  --enable-libaom
  --enable-libmfx
  --enable-amf
  --enable-ffnvcodec
  --enable-cuvid
  --enable-d3d11va
  --enable-nvenc
  --enable-nvdec
  --enable-dxva2
  --enable-avisynth
  --enable-libopenmpt
```

I think that the problem is I didn't enable libnpp when compiling, could It be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure `avcodec_find_encoder_by_name()` is the correct function ?

Did you try `avcodec_find_decoder_by_name` ?

Comment: This and install CUDA sdk seems to work, I feel so stupid!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Sh... happens, don't worry about it ;)